# Как в новом C++11 возвращается список объектов хранящихся в std::list?

Tags: c++, c++11

С приходом C++11 в C++ были добавлены новые возможности и у меня появилось не понимание того, как возвращается список объектов из функции?

Есть код:

```
class SuperObject {
    SuperObject(int a_)
        : a(a_)
    {
    }

private:
    int a = 0;
};

std::list<SuperObject> collectSuperObjects() {
    std::list<SuperObject> tmp;
    // do something with tmp
    return tmp;
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Правильно ли понимаю, что компилятор не будет добавлять в `SuperObject` какие-либо конструкторы в нашем случае, т.к. пользователь написал свой?
2. Как будет возвращаться результат функции `collectSuperObjects`?

Прежде всего меня интересует ситуация с MSVC 2013.

Comment: Поясните, какие конструкторы Вы имеет в виду.

Comment: `c++11` не такой уж и новый. На сегодняшний день актуален `c++14`.

Comment: @alexolut Будем честны, даже `C++11` не всем поддерживается в полном объеме, а уж про `C++14` и говорить не следует ;)

Comment: @sys_dev отнюдь. Clang и gcc уже и зачатки c++17 поддерживают. Вот у MS с этим не очень, насколько я знаю.

Comment: @alexolut к поддержке очередного стандарта приступают не тогда, когда предыдущий уже полностью покрыт :) Впрочем, в GCC из C++0x на данный момент **не** покрыто только "Minimal support for garbage collection and reachability-based leak detection", аутентичность чего в C++ под некоторым сомнением...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Да, конструктора по умолчанию не будет, в С++03 было так же.
2) `tmp` возвращается перемещением, при этом элементы списка не копируются.
(В С++03 тут было бы NRVO, но все равно нужен был бы копирующий конструктор).

Для добавления элемента в список можно использовать `tmp.emplace_back(1);`.

Comment: Так и сейчас будет NRVO, не будет тут перемещения(скорее всего)

Answer (score 5):

В случае `SuperObject` будут сгенерированы конструкторы копирования и перемещения, а также соответствующие операторы копирования и перемещения. Никаких других конструкторов сгенерировано не будет. Чтобы компилятор прекратил генерировать копирующий конструктор, достаточно написать свой. Запретить генерацию перемещающего ещё проще, просто реализуйте что-либо из следующего списка:

- Конструктор копирования
- Конструктор перемещения
- Деструктор
- Оператор копирования
- Оператор перемещения

Но почему такая разница с копирующим конструктором? Потому что старый код нужно поддерживать. Кстати, выше написана не вся правда про генерацию копирующего конструктора, в следующих случаях он будет автоматически сгенерирован как удалённый(`= delete`), если пользователь добавил:

- Конструктор перемещения
- Оператор перемещения

Таким образом, стандарт почти уравнивает два конструктора, только деструктор пока не может запретить копирующий конструктор — это поломало бы очень много кода. Но это уже объявлено как *deprecated*, поэтому в будущем, конструктор копирования не будет генерироваться, если в классе будет деструктор или оператор копирования(пользовательский, я имею в виду):

> **[depr.impldec]**
>
> The implicit definition of a copy constructor as defaulted is
> deprecated if the class has a user-declared copy assignment operator
> or a user-declared destructor. The implicit definition of a copy
> assignment operator as defaulted is deprecated if the class has a
> user-declared copy constructor or a user-declared destructor (12.4,
> 12.8). In a future revision of this International Standard, these implicit definitions could become deleted (8.4).

Про 2 часть вопроса Abyx написал уже — будет либо NRVO, либо перемещение списка. Элементы перемещаться не будут.